# Sum of correlated exponential random variables

Tags: statistics

How do we find PDF of sum of correlated exponential random variables. I know for independent random variables. But how to find it for correlated exponential random variables.

Comment: If they are 100% correlated that means they are essentially the same so the pdf’s would scale by N

Comment: How is the correlation defined?

Comment: Unless you specify the _joint_ PDF of the exponential random variables, your question is not answerable at all.

Comment: @DilipSarwate as an exponential random variable i fully characterized by its mean, I believe if the correlation is defined, we can derive the joint PDF. For example, if we know the transform function $Y=g(X)$ then we know the joint pdf. The fact that both $X$ and $Y$ are exponential makes the calculation easier. Of course, the knowledge about $g(.)$ is crucial.

Comment: @AlexTP Two exponential random variables given means and with specified correlation coefficient can nonetheless have infinitely many different _joint_ pdfs. Furthermore, if $Y=g(X)$ with $X$ an exponential random variable, then $Y$ is _not_ an exponential random variable (as it must be as per the requirements in the problem statement) except when $g$ is a _linear_ function ($g(x) = ax$ with $a > 0$) in which case the correlation coefficient is $1$. Please rethink your comment, and possibly give some thought to deleting it entirely. If you choose to delete, I will delete this response too.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think deleting comments to hide my stupidity is not necessary, not thank to the anonymous Internet, but rather I do not feel guilty to ask stupid questions. (I am also ok with the fact that some people want to hide their lack of intelligence).

Comment: @DilipSarwate  Now, let me continue learning by keep being stupid. Your "furthermore ..." is what I meant: $Y=g(X)$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are exponential, $g(.)$  must the linear function. Maybe I was wrong in saying that "$X$ and $Y$ are correlated, then we can say $Y=g(X)$ with some $g(.)$". Could you please give a counterexample? Also, that is the reason why I asked how the correlation is defined in my first comment.

Comment: @AlexTP If $X$ and $Y$ are correlated random variables, then it is _not necessary_ that $Y$ is a function of $X$, and this has nothing to do with whether the random variables are exponential or otherwise. Furthermore, if $Y=g(X)$, then $X$ and $Y$ don't enjoy a joint **PDF** because all the probability mass lies on the  curve $y=g(x)$ in the $x$-$y$ plane, and the (areal) density, measured in probability mass per uint area, is infinite at points on this curve. The probability mass has _lineal_ density (mass per unit length) along this curve, but not areal density because the curve has 0 area.

Comment: @AlexTP For a specific example of correlated exponential random variables that are _not_ linear functions of each other, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/66776/6633) over on stats.SE (where _this_ question belongs; it has nothing to do with DSP).

Comment: @DilipSarwate I got it, I was wrong about the correlation interpretation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The pdf $f_Z(z)$ of the sum $Z=X+Y$ of *any* two jointly continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is as follows: 
$$\text{For all } z, -\infty < z < \infty, ~~ f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,z-x) \, \mathrm dx.\tag{1}$$

For the special case when $X$ and $Y$ are *nonnegative* random variables (including as a special case, exponential random variables) and so take on nonnegative values only, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ has value $0$ if at least one of $x$ and $y$ is smaller than $0$. Hence, in this case, the *integrand* $f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)$ in $(1)$ has value $0$ if $x < 0$ or if $z < x$. Consequently, if $z$ is a negative number, then the *integrand* in $(1)$ is always $0$ regardless of the value of $x$ and therefore so is the integral. All of which is just a long-winded way of saying that $f_Z(z)$ has value $0$ when $z<0$, that is, $Z$ takes on nonegative values only, which any idiot could have deduced from the fact that $Z=X+Y$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative. But the approach is useful even for $z>0$ since now we have that the *integrand* in $(1)$ is zero when $x<0$ or when $x >z$ and so for nonnegative $X$ and $Y$, we can simplify $(1)$ to
$$f_Z(z) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\int_0^z f_{X,Y}(x,z-x) \, \mathrm dx, & z \geq 0,\\\quad\\
0, & z < 0\end{cases} \tag{2}$$

> No further simplification of $(2)$ is possible *in general*.

For the special case when $X$ and $Y$ are **independent** random variables, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ *factors* into $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ and so $(1)$ becomes the familiar convolution integral and $(2)$ the somewhat-less-familiar convolution integral for causal signals. But **no such simplification is possible for nonindependent random variables** $X$ and $Y$; we need the *joint pdf* to calculate $f_Z(z)$ and just knowing that $X$ and $Y$ are correlated random variables (whether exponential or Gaussian or whatever) is not enough.